# Short story involving survival on a small asteroid; people stranded on it must keep off 'day' side

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration

I have a strong recollection of reading a short story as a kid in the 1980's - 90's about a couple of guys (kids, maybe) that were stranded on an asteroid or moon after some disaster and needed to survive until rescued. The gimmick was that if caught on the "day" side of the asteroid, they would burn up. But because it was so small, they could actually run around it and thus stay ahead of the sunlight for awhile.

My sense is that it was in a magazine, as opposed to a collection of short stories or anything like that. Does anyone else remember this story (e.g. who wrote it, what magazine it was printed in)?

Comment: I cannot find it, but I feel certain it is an Asimov story.

Comment: I remember a short story about an agent fleeing a space cruiser who manages to avoid it by running round one of the moons of mars, keeping on the other side of the moon from the cruiser. That's not it, is it?

Comment: @DJClayworth I read this one (about the moons of mars), and I think it was a Arthur C Clarke story named [Hide-and-Seek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide-and-Seek_%28short_story%29).

Comment: @DJClayworth @DavRob60 I don't think that is it. Obviously, my recollection could be wrong, but I remember the main reason for the "race" being the threat of the sun, not someone chasing him/them.

Comment: @geoffc i think the story you are thinking of takes place on Venus, where a human has to go out on to the surface to recover a robot stuck in the sun due to an order conflicting with the three laws. i may be wrong though, as i have not read all of Asimov's works

Comment: @Matt I know it's not the one you where seeking for, but it's the one @DJClayworth was referring to.

Comment: Right I remember the story, the astronaut is saved from the close sun by the reflecting mirrors of the spaceship before a pod could be sent for his rescue! Very original and satisfying story.

Comment: @Xantec - your story is Roundabout, but it takes place on Mercury.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, after a lot of Google query tweaking, I found it: *Running from the Sun*, by William Forstchen. It appeared in the November 1991 issue of *Boys' Life*. Google Books has it archived, actually:

http://books.google.com/books?id=f_gDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA1&lr&rview=1&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false