# Book about a planet where the main character has to run away from the Sun

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book when I was 11 or 12, and it's killing me now - I just remember that the planet was really hot, and the character had to constantly run away from the Sun to stay alive.

Pretty vague but I'd be so happy if someone could identify, I remember really liking this when I was younger.

Comment: Frost and Fire by Ray Bradbury? It's a short story.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_(short_story)

Comment: Were you “11 or 12” in 2010 or in 1960?

Comment: Maybe "Running from the Sun" by William Forstchen? It was published in 1991.

Comment: summertime on icarus by arthur c clarke might be a partial match... suggest you take the tour of the site and serif you can add more detail, for example when were you 12? Did you read it in english? was it a novel or a short story?... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I was going to post that as an answer, but you've got it first.  It's a good match, and the fact that it was published in *Boy's Life* suggests it's something an 11-year-old might well come across.

Comment: You are a gentleman @DavidW  ;)

Comment: If so it's a dupe of [Short story involving survival on a small asteroid; people stranded on it must keep off 'day' side](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/short-story-involving-survival-on-a-small-asteroid-people-stranded-on-it-must-k).

Answer (score 8):

From your question I'm not sure if you're remembering a novel or a short story. On the off-chance that it was a short story, a possible candidate is *Running from the Sun* by [William Forstchen](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?652). It deals with two young cadets from the "Moon Academy" assigned to an asteroid on an orbit near to the Sun. An accident destroys their shelter, and they have to keep running around the asteroid to always stay in the shade to avoid being cooked alive.

It was published in 1991 in *Boy's Life*. Isfdb doesn't seem to know about it, but a copy is available online at [google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f_gDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA1&lr=&rview=1&pg=PA34&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).